# How to set submit button in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

When I want to calculate the result, I have entered in the textbox.

I connected them successfully with my local database.

But I use these codes to terminate the Score entry if the Students list ended.

```
Dim AssessmentRecords = Select p
                        From p In db.Assessments
                        Where p.Class = cboClass.Text
    If RecordPosition + 1 < AssessmentRecords.Count Then
       MsgBox("End of Records reached!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
       Exit Sub
    End If
```

When I debugged the software, I can't actually enter the score it keeps telling me "End of Records reached"

I don't know how to deals with the problem and sometime I can put only for one person and then terminates and I use LINEQ to SQL in my connection to local database.

I will appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Have you executed the SQL which is run by LINQ on your database? Do you get results?

Comment: Yes i have done everything like connection, attaching all the textboxes with database and so on.

Comment: No. Have you debugged your code, copied the SQL from AssessmentRecord query, pasted in your SQL Management Studio/SQL Developr, executed the query and looked the results?

Comment: Ok Alex, how can i teste it please? Help me

Comment: I already described it. Debug, set a breakpoint at your query, investigate AssessmentRecords, copy the select statement (it´s inside one of the Properties) and execute it in a sql management studio (MS SQL Server) or SQL Devloper (ORacle)

Comment: That means i should download MS SQL Server or Oracle to taste my command? Thank you very much